# How to write conditional expression in Thymeleaf each loop?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm building a nested navigation that shows the `th:fragments` that have been added to a section of the HTML document:

```
<ul>
  <li th:each="section : ${content.getFragments()}">
    <ul>
      <li th:each="subsection : ${subsection.getSubsections()}" th:text="${subsection.title}">Default Subsection</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

The problem is this generates an error if some `section` contains no `subsection`.

How can I check if a `section` contains `subsections`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should reconsider your approach. In general, I try not to return null lists to the UI/Web Tier. This makes situations like this much easier to handle. You should instead return an empty list.

In this specific case, `subsection` should be an empty list.

If this is out of your control, you can check if the list list is null like:

```
<ul>
  <li th:each="section : ${content.getFragments()}">
    <ul th:if= "${subsection != null}">
      <li th:each="subsection : ${subsection.getSubsections()}" th:text="${subsection.title}">Default Subsection</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Very nice thanks a lot. Just for completeness sake, is there a way to do this using conditional expressions with `? <something> : <otherthing>`?

Comment: Maybe something like this? <li th:each="subsection : ${subsection.getSubsections()}" th:text="${subsection.title} ? : 'Default Subsection'"></li>